# How to detect clicks through UI on android device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to detect clicks through UI elements? I made canvas, on canvas there's a draggable/scrollable panel which automatically opens when you press on a gameobject and automatically clothes down if I press anywhere but the gameobject. The problem is whenever I try to scroll somewhere where my finger isn't hovering over a game object, the window clothes down even if I tried to scroll in the area of the panel

```
I am using Raycast to detect a gameobject with a layermask and found another method which is places inside of if statement which check for clicks. Here's my code for panel animation of the up-down movement:


if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //to prevent indicator to be clicked when using UI elements.
            //It is put after checking for button click and before creating Ray
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
                return;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Boutiques"))
                {
                    GetComponent<Animator>().Play("AnimUP");
                }


            }
            else {GetComponent<Animator>().Play("AnimDOWN");
            }
        }
```

I was trying to make a scrollable window which opens when you press on an object with your finger and clothes down if you press somewhere out of the window

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the [touchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) in the Update.
Find a example script:

```
public class TouchPhaseExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 direction;

    public Text m_Text;
    string message;

    void Update()
    {
        //Update the Text on the screen depending on current TouchPhase, and the current direction vector
        m_Text.text = "Touch : " + message + "in direction" + direction;

        // Track a single touch as a direction control.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Handle finger movements based on TouchPhase
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                //When a touch has first been detected, change the message and record the starting position
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    // Record initial touch position.
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    message = "Begun ";
                    break;

                //Determine if the touch is a moving touch
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one
                    direction = touch.position - startPos;
                    message = "Moving ";
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    // Report that the touch has ended when it ends
                    message = "Ending ";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to attach this script(removed Text variable) to a panel that I use to scroll and I can still press "through" it and window still clothes down. Does it work on android devices or is there something else I should use?